# Graph that consider the columns of a matrix as series

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi everybody I am working with a matrix in R. This matrix named `Matriz.Colocacion` has five columns, each column show info about different years 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 and 2013. Row names of `Matriz.Colocacion` have the month for each year. My matrix has the next form (I include `dput()` version of `Matriz.Colocacion` in the final part):

```
                 2009       2010       2011       2012       2013
enero       710004.35 1458624.41 6229245.09 4407422.89 3006568.05
febrero     889398.08  942099.60 5553163.01 4248144.11 2615730.00
marzo      1114883.11 1210951.20 6372919.90 3537103.40 2833299.10
abril      1419242.11 1151423.89 6755054.64 3500595.75 3438797.32
mayo       1585857.22 1598355.10 7119008.27 4049074.18 3224926.48
junio      1010455.56 1370856.78 7585411.87 3279868.96 2794029.57
julio      1292333.35 1420547.36 7402737.51 3420974.23 3003458.16
agosto     1032443.35 2048291.06 7250944.21 2602310.30 2486931.57
septiembre 1133260.11 3043637.60 6227706.73 2225635.25 2515076.46
octubre    1229593.84 3669634.09 5795989.01 2853467.41 2674568.38
noviembre  1074569.64 3641665.16 4015226.43 4178671.47       0.00
diciembre  1370905.58 6780879.37 5391952.87 2831027.32       0.00
```

My problem got when I try to build the graph. I don't know if it is better to separe my matrix in individual series or if there is anyway to use all matrix to plot my wished graph. I would like to get a graphic like this:[image]

Where in x axis are showed `row.names(Matriz.Colocacion)` and in the legend of the graph are showed the diferent years of the matrix (2009,2010,2011,2012,2013).

I don't have enough knowledge of ggplot and I am having some trouble trying to create this graph. The `dput()` version of my matrix is the next:

```
structure(c(710004.35, 889398.08, 1114883.11, 1419242.11, 1585857.22, 
1010455.56, 1292333.35, 1032443.35, 1133260.11, 1229593.84, 1074569.64, 
1370905.58, 1458624.41, 942099.6, 1210951.2, 1151423.89, 1598355.1, 
1370856.78, 1420547.36, 2048291.06, 3043637.6, 3669634.09, 3641665.16, 
6780879.37, 6229245.09, 5553163.01, 6372919.9, 6755054.64, 7119008.27, 
7585411.87, 7402737.51, 7250944.21, 6227706.73, 5795989.01, 4015226.43, 
5391952.87, 4407422.89, 4248144.11, 3537103.4, 3500595.75, 4049074.18, 
3279868.96, 3420974.23, 2602310.3, 2225635.25, 2853467.41, 4178671.47, 
2831027.32, 3006568.05, 2615730, 2833299.1, 3438797.32, 3224926.48, 
2794029.57, 3003458.16, 2486931.57, 2515076.46, 2674568.38, 0, 
0), .Dim = c(12L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("enero", "febrero", 
"marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", 
"octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"), c("2009", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013")))
```

I wait you can help me. Thanks a lot of.

Comment: You need to read some basic texts about `ggplot`, e.g. [**this**](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/). You will find that data should be in a 'long' (as opposed to 'wide') format. There are heaps of nice posts on [**this topic on SO**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+[ggplot]+time+series).

Comment: +1 for an excellent question, example data plus a clear example of what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to get your data in the correct format:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

dat_melt = melt(dat)
dat_melt = within(dat_melt, { 
   Var2 = as.factor(Var2) 
   Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = c('enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre'))
  })

ggplot(dat_melt, aes(x = Var1, y = value, color = Var2, group = Var2)) + 
   geom_line() + 
   scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

[image]

This question is a bit more tricky than I first thought. Both the `color` and the `group` aesthetic are needed in this case because the x-axis is a `factor` variable and `ggplot2` normally will not connect the points when using `geom_line`, see [this link](http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/faq-geom_line-doesnt-draw-lines/) for more information.

Comment: x-axis doesn't have proper ordering

Comment: That is because it is ordered alphabetically. Changing that can be done using the `factor` function, more specifically the `levels` argument.

Comment: Thanks dear @PaulHiemstra but how can I correct the order in x axis that would be a trouble for me!

Comment: I added the solution, do read the documentation of the functions I use carefully to learn and understand what is happening.

Comment: Many thanks master @PaulHiemstra awesome only aditional question in y axis it is possible not to get scientific notation for numbers or maybe another format for numbers maybe some links to solve this thanks another time

Comment: That can be done using the `scale_y_continuous` function, googling for `ggplot2 avoid scientific notation` will lead you to some good examples.

Comment: Many thanks @PaulHiemstra for the help I checked ggplot book but I don't get enough advice as you, and Merry Cristhmas jojojo

Comment: Last little question @PaulHiemstra in the last column of my matrix I have values of 0 if I replace 0 for NA could I get the plot without the line that is showed in those months or what can I do to make this

Comment: @Duck give it a try first, if you get stuck you can always ask a new question.